# Is there a way to upload large file in chunks/blocks through Amazon Workdocs api or it's client provider?

Tags: amazon-workdocs

I completed the upload file part in Workdocs via rest api's.
But in that, how does Workdocs handles large file upload, saw the InitiateDocumentVersionUpload api which doesnot indicate the restrictions on file size if any.